# Correct typographic way to start a list ':-' or ':'

Tags: typography

Ive been having a conversation with some one who starts lists like this `:-` so in context it would be

> My List :-
>
> - Item 1
> - Item 2
> - Item 3

Ive always written it as `:` so it would be

> My List :
>
> - Item 1
> - Item 2
> - Item 3

Is there any correct way to do this or do they mean different things ?

Comment: I have never seen a hyphen used in this context, but in most languages (a notable exception being French), no space is used before the colon.

Comment: I have never seen colon+dash before. Can you provide some more details regarding why they are suggesting that? FWIW, one can argue that the bulleted list is pretty clear indicator that it's a list and that any punctuation is redundant. (That said, I've only ever seen the second--never the first).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language usage and would probably be a better fit for http://English.stackexchange.com

Comment: Looks like your question has already been answered over there: [Is it proper to use a colon followed immediately by a hyphen?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31060)

Comment: I don't entirely agree that this is off topic. This is a place where there's large overlap. It's not really about language usage, but typographic style, which many would argue is absolutely graphic-design related. I love the answer on JohnB's link! But I'm still walking away not entirely satisfied...I'd really like to know more about the history/habit of this particular typographic treatment. If the OP is willing, I'd strongly recommend rewording the question to ask about the history of it's usage. (Which in turn, would help answer modern day applicability).

Comment: I agree with @DA01 - it is not really off-topic.

Comment: Fair enough:— still seems like language usage to me though :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English usage and would be a better fit at http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess that the person you had a conversation with is Indian.

Comment: And, for fun, here's something of mine on the topic from a few years ago: http://thegrumpywriter.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/plurals-and-emoticons/

Comment: @AnandaMahto - British actually

Comment: @sam, Hmmm. I've only seen this in Indian print.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language use, and not design.

Answer (score -3):

I would stick with the simple colon  :

To me, the other one looks like a mistake.  Good luck!